# Add to empty text node of anchor if empty using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a WP website that uses an ecommerce plugin; amongst other things this plugin stores and retrieves product images. Trouble is that, if the product has no image assigned it returns an anchor tag with nothing in the text node as follows:

```
<a id="product_image_id" href="..."></a>
```

I'd like to stay away from messing with the core functions of the plugin so that I can stay on the upgrade path and would like to use PHP to check the returned string for an empty text node and replace it with a 'no image available' image like so:

```
<a id="product_image_id" href="..."><img src="..." /></a>
```

I've tried all manner of PHP sub string / replace functions without any success and have hit a wall.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us the code, link to the plugin. Why don't you assign your "no image available"-image to the product?

Comment: @Bergi The trouble with assigning the "no image available"-image to the product is that this store is part of a WP Multi Site with multiple users, whom cannot all be counted on to add the image in. The Plugin is MarketPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, here is how I solved it:

```
$thumbnail = function_that_returns_formatted_image();
$thumbnail_content = strip_tags($thumbnail, '<img>'); // Strip out </a> and ignore </img>
if (empty($thumbnail_content)) // Check for </img> tag
    $thumbnail = '<img src="/path/to/temporary_image.jpg" />';
```

I hope this helps some one!

Answer (score 1):

Glad you solved it!

I had a solution based on SimpleXmlElement in mind:

```
$xs2 = '<a id="product_image_id" href="..."><img src="..." /></a>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xs2);

foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
  echo $child->getName();
```

By look at the childern, it is easy to see if there is a image present. I not, add a node and return the `SimpleXMLElement->asXml`;